# How to resolve table _fwbk_wp_media_file_manager_log error message

Tags: wordpress, innodb

I would like to import demo content on WordPress via demo content install
but I get this error message:

Failed to create 
tmp table _fwbk_wp_media_file_manager_log

You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'
at line 3

How can I resolve this problem? If you need any other details don't hesitate to question from me about that

Comment: Well, show us the statement.  The problem is at or immediately before `ENGINE...`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Revert: [ThemeFuse/Unyson-Backups-Extension@9fc1a53](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Backups-Extension/commit/9fc1a538513ecc8c01e228c82debd1e8a4647fc6)
2. Remove `GLOBAL` keyword from the first query: `$wpdb->query( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0' );`
3. Remove the whole third line: `$wpdb->query( 'SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1' );`

**As per support:**

1) Don’t use unyson briny editor. The unyson plugin is used only for dummy data importing.

You can use our own Visual Composer editor.

2) Get into Admin Panel > Appearance > Customize > Site Header > Header Style > Show Top Bar

Please refer the attached video : http://recordit.co/Kdr8apkSwp

Note : We hope you had a great experience with our theme and support. Please take one minute to share your feedback by clicking on a rating below.

Kindly refer the attached url : http://recordit.co/YqdTBuEJRm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after revert to your advice in the first step, I tried again, I got this error message: Failed to create tmp table _fwbk_wp_media_file_manager_log. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: This mean you don't have permission to write or create table.

Comment: I checked this link but I cannot get a result, I don't have a permission problem, By the way, I think I should wait for other answers if it has been available